# converting xemacs lisp to run in emacs

Tags: elisp, xemacs

I have used xemacs for years and have a lot of lisp code I have written.
Now I want to switch to emacs and convert all the lisp code over to work in emacs.  This is on an winXP machine.

I'm sure I am not the first one to convert code back and forth.  Does anyone know what differences to expect? Are there any documents out there explaining the differences I need to watch for in converting lisp code?

Comment: An example of the kind of thing I was asking for is the fact that emacs has the menu as part of the keymap, where xemacs has the  menu as a list, separately.  so now I know that any lisp code that adds to the menu or the pop-up menu has to be changed.  That is the kind of thing I was asking for--general directions about the ways these two editor differ from each other regarding lisp code.  I'm sorry that is too broad for some people. I can hardly post 164K of lisp code and ask specifically where they would be different, could I?  *That* would be too broad.

Comment: indeed, this is why I answered the question with a general recommendation. Now you need to byte compile your code and isolate specific issue and ask about them separately, one by one.

Comment: don't forget to [close the question by accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439)

Answer (score 4):

The *language* is pretty much the same Emacs Lisp.

Some functionality is different: functions may be missing or be named differently, or accept different argument &c &c.

I suggest that you start with byte-compiling the code and carefully examine all the errors and warnings.

After you fix all of them, chances are you are golden.

Comment: You're conveniently forgetting the extra features Xemacs had, the most prominent one being extents which behave like a combination of text properties and overlays.  Porting that code over will require more skill to decide which of the two behaviors was intended, look at the Xemacs compatibility code for examples.

Comment: @wasamasa: each feature (e.g., extents) requires a separate effort. The question is very general and my answer had to be correspondingly general.

Comment: thanks for the tip @#wasamasa.  I had not thought about byte-compiling the coded as a way to find what runs or doesn't.